# How secure is GPG symmetric encryption?

Tags: asymmetric, gnupg

Since I am new to encryption and have recently been losing stuff, I decided to start a file that contains some passwords for online accounts and whatnot, encrypt it, back it up (and keep a single copy on Google Drive....cloud storage seems insecure to me.)

I was wondering about using GPG though.

Is the default algorithm, CAST5, sufficient? `gpg -c file` uses it

Is there any chance that my file could be broken by Google? It uses a long password that seems secure.

Should I add extra information throughout to act as "additional entropy"? Maybe `dd if=/dev/random >> file`

And the most important question...is GPG even right for this job-encrypting basic text files. Is there a better, mroe secure option, or a faster option?

Comment: Google Drive IS cloud storage ...

Comment: Why not a password manager? KeePass, LastPass, Password1, etc.?

Comment: @schroeder I don't know...what if I forget my master password to one of those? And yes, I know GD is cloud, but I still feel weird. They suddenly have **all** of my data, but they probably did before anyways.

Comment: What happens if you lose your password to the GPG-encrypted file?

Comment: A password manager also has the ability to use 2FA, which is a huge boost to the security of the data.

Comment: I know for a fact that I won't lose the password for my GPG file. It's a very simple password...

Will a password manager let me import current password or specify them? Which one is good for Firefox on Linux?

Comment: Why are you concerned about Google "breaking" your file?  Is there some reason you think they'd go to immense expense to try to do so?

Comment: So, you want to encrypt the file, post it on Google Drive, and use a very simple password to decrypt it? I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to secure against ....

Comment: As for password manager features and options, it will take 5 minutes to look at their homepages and choose one that works for you.

Comment: @David No, not really, just don't feel like they need all of my passwords and stuff...even though they probably already do _Thank you oh mighty Google in the sky!_

schroeder, by simple I don't mean "easy to brute force or guess" I more meant "extremely easy to remember"

Comment: Then you could use the same 'simple' password for the password manager ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CAST-5` aka `CAST-128` is a fine choice of algorithm.  It probably hasn't had as much cryptanalysis as, say, AES, but there are no significant publicly-known weaknesses in the algorithm.  It's a 128-bit cipher, which is computationally infeasible to brute force, and so all of the security depends on the security of your passphrase.  GPG performs a technique known as "key stretching" (see the s2k options) to make it harder to brute force passphrases as well.

GPG is a great tool for encrypting text files -- that's basically what it's designed to do.  (Encrypt arbitrary blocks of data.)  You can use a password manager if you prefer to have your data structured/managed for you, or select something that plugs in to your browser.

> Should I add extra information throughout to act as "additional entropy"? Maybe `dd if=/dev/random >> file`

This won't do any good.  Modern crypto algorithms are not dependent upon any entropy present in the plaintext, but only in the key being used.  A known-plaintext attack on a cipher would render it dead from a cryptography point-of-view, so this should not be your concern.

Comment: Alright, so suing GPG is fine, and the default of CAST-128 is also fine. I assume it wouldn't even compare to AES-256, but then I'd have to actually **learn** how to use GPG because trying that it asks for UIDs and whatnot

Comment: gpg --cipher-algo AES256 if you want it.

Comment: Will I have to remember that when I go to decrypt it or will GPG automatically handle that?

Comment: GPG adds a header to the file that includes the algorithm used, so it will know which algorithm to use when decrypting.

Comment: I think choosing a good password is more important than the algorithm. If the password was a simple dictionary word, then no cipher algo can save